# I am not able parse a table element within a div using JSOUP

Tags: html, web-scraping, jsoup

```
   <div id="fareSelectModifySearch"> 
     <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"> 
      <tbody>
           <tr> 
            <td style="padding-left:8px;"><strong>1 Traveler(s)</strong> &nbsp;<span     id="routeInfo">     New York, NY (JFK) to Las Vegas, NV (LAS) on 09/20/2013</span></td> 
           </tr>  
      </tbody>
     </table> 
    </div>
```

I want to extract the `td` element data , i.e

> 1 Traveler(s)New York, NY (JFK) to Las Vegas, NV (LAS) on 09/20/2013

Can anyone please give me the source code for this using `Jsoup` library.

Comment: What have you come up with on your own so far?

Comment: Are you looking to hire someone here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This**

```
Document site2 = Jsoup.connect("http://wl.filegenie.com/~ikp4success/test.html")

                .timeout(3000000)

                .get();


        String values = site2.select("td").text();
        System.out.println(values);
```

i upload the file to my server FYI.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the .text() method?

From jSoup Documentaion.

```
 String text() 
      Get the combined text of all the matched elements.
```